# Combine array to one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$settings = array(
    'name' => array(
        0 => 'Large Pouch',
        1 => 'XL Pouch'
    ),
    'size' => array(
        0 => '9x14',
        1 => '12x18'
    ),
    'weight' => array(
        0 => '10',
        1 => '20'
    ),
    'metro_manila_price' => array(
        0 => '59',
        1 => '79'
    ),
    'luzvimin_price' => array(
        0 => '89',
        1 => '139'
    )
);
```

I wanted to put the values from that array to one array. `$shipping_options` with format of
for example:

```
$shipping_options = array(
    '0' => 'Large Pouch 9x14 - $59',
    '1' => 'XL Pouch 12x18 - $79'
);
```

How to program this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a loop:

```
$shipping_options = array();
foreach ($settings['name'] as $key => $value) {
   $value = sprintf('%s(%s) - $%s', 
                    $value, 
                    $settings['size'][$key], 
                    $settings['metro_manila_price'][$key]);
   $shipping_options[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
foreach ($settings['name'] as $key => $value) {
    $shipping_options[$key] = $settings['name'][$key] . " " . $settings['size'][$key] . " - $" .    $settings['metro_manila_price'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
echo "<pre>";
$size = count($settings['name']);
$shipping_options = array();
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
{
    $shipping_options[$i] = $settings['name'][$i]."(".$settings['size'][$i].") - $".$settings['metro_manila_price'][$i];
}

print_r($shipping_options);
```